# automatic extension update can't handle zip file from github?

Tags: joomla, github, joomla2.5

I have an extension hosted on github, for which I want to provide automatic updates. However, when I provide the URL to a file attached to a release, Joomla just reports the following on trying to automatically update:

```
Fehler beim Verbindungsaufbau zum Server: Error Unknown
Ungültige Webadresse
```

Translation

```
Error in connecting to server: Error Unknown
Invalid web address
```

It's the same when trying to install from the web address via the Extensions - Install page.
From the browser, I can download the file just fine however.
Anybody got an idea why that is? Is it an error on github side, or on Joomla's?
Or is it some "safety" or "security" mechanism on github side?
What can I do to avoid it? Or do those two just not play along?

Example URL: https://github.com/codeling/bfstop/releases/download/1.2.0/pkg_bfstop-1.2.0.zip

**Edit:**

Inserted the patch for downloadPackage method (gist.github.com/piotr-cz/8316210) mentioned by piotr_cz in the comments below the answer into my Joomla installation now.

URL passed into the method after resolving the redirect: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/6794712/f2aa5eb4-7838-11e3-837a-c6be2639e4ca.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dpkg_bfstop-1.2.0.zip&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1389455424&Signature=Nnyl6TnWueTqK8bPkPXUidM8UzQ%3D`

URL after the newly inserted lines: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/6794712/f2aa5eb4-7838-11e3-837a-c6be2639e4ca.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=pkg_bfstop-1.2.0.zip&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1389455424&Signature=Nnyl6TnWueTqK8bPkPXUidM8UzQ=`

The response is still a 505 error:

```
response: JHttpResponse Object
(
    [code] => 505
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Date] => Sat, 11 Jan 2014 15:49:24 GMT
            [Connection] => close
            [Server] => AmazonS3
        )

    [body] =>
)
```

So I suppose the encoding doesn't matter. The error 505 would indeed indicate http version problems? Why would Joomla and Amazon disagree on HTTP versions? Definitely not an HTTP expert here but version 1.1 should be the unchanged standard version since more than 10 years now?

Answer (score 2):

Conclusions:

1. **Automatically generated downloads** by GitHub's *Tags* and *Releases* are compatible with Joomla Installer at this moment (Jan 2014) as long as the repository name matches extension name (element). Joomla Installer is able to work with an extension which:

   - Have files and folders located directly:

     ```
     mod_mymodule.zip:

     /mod_mymodule.xml
     /mod_mymodule.php
     ```
   - Or have files and folders located in a folder of the same name as the archive (see [`JInstallerHelper::unpack`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/installer/helper.php#L143)):

     ```
     mod_mymodule.zip:

     /mod_mymodule
     /mod_mymodule/mod_mymodule.xml
     /mod_mymodule/mod_mymodule.php
     ```

     This is how GitHub *Tags* and *Releases* are built now. Automatically generated downloads of repository `mod_mymodule` results in `mod_mymodule-[tag/branch].zip` archive with `mod_mymodule-[tag/branch]` subfolder. Say when we tag extension `1.0.0-beta`:

     ```
     mod_mymodule-1.0.0-beta.zip:

     /mod_mymodule-1.0.0-beta
     /mod_mymodule-1.0.0-beta/mod_mymodule.xml 
     /mod_mymodule-1.0.0-beta/mod_mymodule.php
     ```

     Note: *There were some changes in how archive is built (see [Automatic Extension Update: Unknown Archive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362958/automatic-extension-update-unknown-archive-type))*
2. **Manually attached Binaries** added to a GitHub *Release* are hosted in the [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/). Request to download these by [JInstallerHelper::downloadPackage](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/installer/helper.php) results in an response `505 HTTP Version Not Supported` and we didn't find a working solution for this problem yet.

In the end one may use GitHub as an Joomla Extensions Update server (it's pretty convenient), as long as you use automatically generated downloads.

GitHub provides *Version Control* service, not an *Update server* so the way how downloadable archive is built may change again in future.

Until we find out a way how to download Attached Binaries (where one have full control over archive's name and structure) using Joomla Installer, GitHub should not be perceived as a reliable tool for Joomla extension updates. I believe there's a way to patch the [JInstaller](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/libraries/cms/installer) package to be compatible with the AWS (download works fine using command-line `curl`).

*Thanks for [ccpl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52834/cppl) and [RandolphCarter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671366/randolphcarter) on getting information for this answer.*

Comment: regarding the note to the second option under 1: I don't think github reverted anything. They just changed from directly zipping folder contents (i.e. the structure mentioned in the first point under 1), to zipping them inside a folder with the name of the repo. Your post at the moment to me reads like they changed it to contain the subfolder and then changed it back? And regarding patching Joomal: Would be nice if the package from s3 worked. maybe joomla forum would be a better place to ask if somebody knows a fix?

Comment: Okay, I'll update the answer. The problem I see is that they can change it again to something else that won't work anymore. As for discussion, I recommend [Joomla CMS Development](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/joomla-dev-cms) Group. I guess other developers will be interested in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that URL is redirected to an S3 location:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/6794712/6c173582-77ef-11e3-9aec-c8994b691269.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dpkg_bfstop-1.2.0.zip&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1389163120&Signature=c4RdRTAUZ5%2FDHlpg0vR2ivK6lQQ%3D`
```

As a guess I would say this breaks the install from web.

#### Updated

Doing a bit further tracking, I can see the `downloadPackage()` method does catch the `302 Found` and try to get the file from the new URL. At this point it does a new `curl` request with some basic `options`:

```php
$options = array("10036" => "GET",
"10065" => "/Users/cppl/Sites/jdev/libraries/joomla/http/transport/cacert.pem",
"10002" => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/github-cloud/releases/6794712/f2aa5eb4-7838-11e3-837a-c6be2639e4ca.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment; filename=pkg_bfstop-1.2.0.zip&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1389170600&Signature=BVlqH0hVhYGjbeKn6w/9nDn+kDg=",
"42" => "1",
"19913" => "1")
```

Unfortunately the S3 service is returning a `505`

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 08:47:59 GMT
Connection: close
Server: AmazonS3
```

Hacking around in `\JHttpTransportCurl\request` I tried

1. forcing `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1`
2. disabling SSL verification `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` (useful in other S3 situations)
3. updating the `cacert.pem` to [the current one](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
4. all together

Nothing worked.

So far it all appears to be on AWS side, I'm not aware of all the S3 access controls possibly there's something in the GitHub setup of their S3 buckets.

Comment: Anything one can do about that? Above URL obviously isn't valid forever (Expires parameter) and thus can't be used directly. Aren't redirects a quite normal thing which thus should not break Joomla updater?

Comment: See my update, basically it's both on the Amazon side and Joomla side, not sure which.

Comment: Can it be that Curl is sending the `HTTP/1.0` version instead of 1.1? I'd try to hack the [JHttpTransportCurl](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/http/transport/curl.php) to use `$options[CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION] = CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1;`

Comment: Nope I tried that, I also tried disabling SSL verification, I'll update the answer with the things I've tried.

Comment: What was the response? 505 should be `The server does not support the HTTP protocol version used in the request.`. Other option could be `CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER` or the `CURLOPT_URL` (10002) might have to be rawurlencoded

Comment: I'm pretty sure now the problem is that the amazonaws url should be rawurlencoded in the [downloadPackage](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/installer/helper.php#L52) method. I just don't know if whole url or only spaces.

Comment: Local CURL installation uses `/github-cloud/releases/6794712/f2aa5eb4-7838-11e3-837a-c6be2639e4ca.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dpkg_bfstop-1.2.0.zip&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAISTNZFOVBIJMK3TQ&Expires=1389178236&Signature=A4Uswim%2FxEuEQr1ESUwxE816VlE%3D`

Comment: Here's my patch for `downloadPackage` method: https://gist.github.com/piotr-cz/8316210.

Comment: @piotr_cz tried to apply your patch to the best of my knowledge, and now it reports all the "error unknown" line, and then "package download failed", so there seems to be a slight change, but not really much...

Comment: [`Error Unknown`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/2.5.x/libraries/joomla/installer/helper.php) in J2.5 means the response code is different than 200 and 302. Try to check new value for the `$url` and `$response` variable.

Comment: How did it go? I'm planning to use Github for extension updates later on, but don't have time ATM to test the patch.

Comment: @piotr_cz see my updated question. in short: the answer is still a 505

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the direct approach to work (to use the release assets for automatic update), therefore I am now implementing the workaround solution by putting the files into the git repository.

Not an ideal solution, I know, but at least that works.

Comment: This is my recent repo and github update works: https://github.com/piotr-cz/mod_freshmail2. Tested from localhost on Joomla 3.0.3

Comment: okay I realized that I'm linking to release files generated automatically, while you to uploaded binary files.

Comment: @piotr_cz the difference between automatically generated and uploaded binary files is that the automatically generated ones link directly to github servers while binary link to s3. And the really sad part is that in principle, I would be fine with the automatically generated ones - just that they contain this additional top-level directory which joomla can't deal with - how are you handling that? At least in my tests, Joomla would also come up with an error if there is just the directory in the zip file and no xml file on top level

Comment: This seems to work at least on J3.x. Important thing is that the archive must have same name as the compressed folder. So inside `mod_mymodule.zip` there should be a `/my_mymodule` folder (see source of [JInstallHelper::unpack](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/installer/helper.php#L143)) and this is how GitHub creates rerelases for me.

Comment: You're right. It also works on J2.5. Because that's exactly what I had to go away from when they introduced that folder - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362958/automatic-extension-update-unknown-archive-type . No idea what changed in the meantime, just glad that it works again! Maybe you'd like to post it as an answer?